# Change button content with css: text from right to left

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I want to have a button that is changing the content if someone hovers over it. I have covered this already. However, I don't know how to have the result I want. I want to have it animated. When someone hovers over the button the new text should fly in from the right to the left and should push out the current text. Futermore I want to have a little sissers icon on the right (inside the button) which also changes the background color when hovering the sisser icon.

Is this possible and if yes how? I haven't found a solution on StackOverflow or codepen which is close to what I want. This is what I have so far:

```css
.product-voucherButton span {
    display: none;
}

.product-voucherButton:hover span {
    display: block;
}

.product-voucherButton:before {
    content: 'Voucher';
}

.product-voucherButton:hover:before {
    content: '';
}

.btn-secondary {
    background-color: #312C2B !important;
    color: white !important;
    border: none !important;
}

.btn {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: .9rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    -webkit-transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-secondary product-voucherButton"><span>this is my code</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements and the `attr()` function:

```css
#btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#btn::before,
#btn::after {
  display: block;
  transition: all .6s ease-in;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  white-space: pre;
}

i.fa.fa-cut {
  transition: all .6s ease-in;
  width: 400px;
}

#btn::before {
  content: attr(data-orig);
}

#btn::after {
  content: attr(data-repl);
  margin-left: 300px;
}

#btn:hover::before {
  margin-left: -300px;
}

#btn:hover::after {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

i.fa.fa-cut {
  margin-left: 363px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#btn:hover i.fa.fa-cut {
  margin-left: 163px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<button id="btn" data-repl="Replacement Text" data-orig="Original Text">

<i class="fa fa-cut"></i>
</button>
```

Update:

You can do this with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements and the `attr()` function:

```css
#btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#btn > span,
#btn::before {
  display: block;
  transition: all .6s ease-in;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  white-space: pre;
}

i.fa.fa-cut {
  transition: all .6s ease-in;
}

#btn::before {
  content: attr(data-orig);
}

#btn > span {
  content: attr(data-repl);
  margin-left: 400px;
}

#btn:hover::before {
  margin-left: -300px;
}

#btn:hover > span {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

i.fa.fa-cut {
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<button id="btn" data-orig="Original Text">

<span>Replacement Text <i class="fa fa-cut"></i></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Oh thanks! Very good and close to what I want. Is the Replacement Text also jumping on your screen? And do you have any idea on how to add a sissers icon to the right 1/4 of the button when the replacement text shows up? (in the best case the sissers icon flys in from left to right as well as the replacement text)

Comment: @Jan I'm not seeing the jumping. I added the scissors. The transition doesn't line up exactly with the text slide, so you may have to tweak it a bit.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I will do. However, the text is jumping when sliding in.. sadly

Comment: @jan Jumping how?

Comment: Here, check this out. First browser is chrome, second one is firefox: https://imgur.com/ZHTzV5M

Comment: @Jan Should be fixed now. I set `white-space: pre` on the b and a elements, also tweaked the margin-left value for Firefox.

Comment: by any change to have a button with a bootstrap column layout of 3/4 for the content and 1/4 for the icon. Cause I would like to have a fixed with for the replacement text and to have it aligned left (the replacement text will have different lengths and will be cutted of and replaced with "...".

Comment: also with a bootstrap layout of 3/4 and 1/4 I can make sure the content is accurately centered!